# VBA and Excel - add to selection cells from array()

Tags: excel, vba, production

Firstly, I would like to thank you in advance for all the answers.

I've got an "end" array which contains row numbers.

```
  If OptionButton1 = True Then

    Dim arraydodrukowania() As String
    ReDim arraydodrukowania(1 To o, 1 To 2)

    For j = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1)

  If array1(j, 9) = 1 And array1(j, 8) = ComboBox2.Value Then

 arraydodrukowania(j, 1) = array1(j, 9)
 arraydodrukowania(j, 2) = array1(j, 2)


Else
End If
```

what I want to do is to select all rows defined by array values

I know that the selection method should be avoided, but it can not be omitted at this occasion.

So, in other words, I need a code which will loop trough the array and will add row no defined by the value in the array to selection. 
The result would be (for example) row no. 2, 5, 1456, 2354 are selected.

the problem here is that the number of rows that needs to be selected varies.

So

```
For j = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1)
    array1(j,1).<ADD TO SELECTION>

next j
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do with the selected rows?

Comment: @BigBen, That's a part of a bigger macro, Lets imagine you've got a production plan where you  certain cells represent a product. When you select these cells and then run it you send link to production drawing associated with the cell to the printer.

Comment: How many cells do you want to select? And are you selecting the entire row, or just cells in a certain column, e.g. A2, A5, A1456, and A2354?

Comment: @Big Ben, It will be condition based, but in general I won't have to select all row, just the cells defined by intersect of rows from the array and certain column numbers.

Comment: Then build up a range address with the columns in question and the row numbers in the array, and then select from there.

Comment: @BigBen. Hmm so basically I need to define a range, add all addresses to that range and then select this range. I will try it, thanks.